# SP Online : overview of all folders and documents with permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder

For my team site I changed permissions for different folders and documents. And now I need some kind of overview of permissions and folders/documents. It there a way where can I see all of this or a way how to export it into a excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or download the trial version of ShareGate and run the Permissions Matrix report

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following PowerShell. It used script [Load-CSOMProperties.ps1](https://gist.github.com/glapointe/cc75574a1d4a225f401b).

Refer to:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/CSOM-Query-All-Unique-e60f2148

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

  $pLoadCSOMProperties=(get-location).ToString()+"\Load-CSOMProperties.ps1"
 . $pLoadCSOMProperties

$properties=@{SiteUrl='';SiteTitle='';ListTitle='';Type='';RelativeUrl='';ParentGroup='';MemberType='';MemberName='';MemberLoginName='';Roles='';}; 

$UserInfoList=""; 

$RootWeb=""; 

$RootSiteTitle="";
$ExportFileDirectory = (get-location).ToString();

$SiteCollectionUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter site collection URL: ";

$Username =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter userName: ";

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password: " -AsSecureString ;

Function PermissionObject($_object,$_type,$_relativeUrl,$_siteUrl,$_siteTitle,$_listTitle,$_memberType,$_parentGroup,$_memberName,$_memberLoginName,$_roleDefinitionBindings)
{
    $permission = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties; 
    $permission.SiteUrl =$_siteUrl; 
    $permission.SiteTitle = $_siteTitle; 
    $permission.ListTitle = $_listTitle; 
    $permission.Type = $_type; 
    $permission.RelativeUrl = $_relativeUrl; 
    $permission.MemberType = $_memberType; 
    $permission.ParentGroup = $_parentGroup; 
    $permission.MemberName = $_memberName; 
    $permission.MemberLoginName = $_memberLoginName; 
    $permission.Roles = $_roleDefinitionBindings -join ","; 

   ## Write-Host  "Site URL: " $_siteUrl  "Site Title"  $_siteTitle  "List Title" $_istTitle "Member Type" $_memberType "Relative URL" $_RelativeUrl "Member Name" $_memberName "Role Definition" $_roleDefinitionBindings -Foregroundcolor "Green";
    return $permission;
}


Function QueryUniquePermissionsByObject($_web,$_object,$_Type,$_RelativeUrl,$_siteUrl,$_siteTitle,$_listTitle)
{
  $_permissions =@();

  Load-CSOMProperties -object $_object -propertyNames @("RoleAssignments") ;

  $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;

  foreach($roleAssign in $_object.RoleAssignments){
      $RoleDefinitionBindings=@(); 
      Load-CSOMProperties -object $roleAssign -propertyNames @("RoleDefinitionBindings","Member");
      $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;
      $roleAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings|%{ 
      Load-CSOMProperties -object $_ -propertyNames @("Name");
      $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;
      $RoleDefinitionBindings += $_.Name; 
    }

    $MemberType = $roleAssign.Member.GetType().Name; 

    $collGroups = "";
      if($_Type  -eq "Site")
      {
          $collGroups = $_web.SiteGroups;
          $ctx.Load($collGroups);
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;
      }

   if($MemberType -eq "Group" -or $MemberType -eq "User")
    { 

        Load-CSOMProperties -object $roleAssign.Member -propertyNames @("LoginName","Title");
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;    

        $MemberName = $roleAssign.Member.Title; 

        $MemberLoginName = $roleAssign.Member.LoginName;    

        if($MemberType -eq "User")
        {
         $ParentGroup = "NA";
        }
        else
        {
         $ParentGroup = $MemberName;
        }

        $_permissions += (PermissionObject $_object $_Type $_RelativeUrl $_siteUrl $_siteTitle $_listTitle $MemberType $ParentGroup $MemberName $MemberLoginName $RoleDefinitionBindings); 

       if($_Type  -eq "Site" -and $MemberType -eq "Group")
       {
          foreach($group in $collGroups)
          {
            if($group.Title -eq $MemberName)
             {
              $ctx.Load($group.Users);
              $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;  
               ##Write-Host "Number of users" $group.Users.Count;
              $group.Users|%{ 
              Load-CSOMProperties -object $_ -propertyNames @("LoginName");
              $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ; 

              $_permissions += (PermissionObject $_object "Site" $_RelativeUrl $_siteUrl $_siteTitle "" "GroupMember" $group.Title $_.Title $_.LoginName $RoleDefinitionBindings); 
                  ##Write-Host  $permissions.Count
                 }
               }
          }
       } 
     }

   }
  return $_permissions;

}

Function QueryUniquePermissions($_web)
 {
  ##query list, files and items unique permissions
  $permissions =@();
  Write-Host "Querying web " +  $_web.Title  ;
  $siteUrl = $_web.Url; 

  $siteRelativeUrl = $_web.ServerRelativeUrl; 

  Write-Host $siteUrl -Foregroundcolor "Red"; 

  $siteTitle = $_web.Title; 

  Load-CSOMProperties -object $_web -propertyNames @("HasUniqueRoleAssignments");
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 ## See more at: https://www.itunity.com/article/loading-specific-values-lambda-expressions-sharepoint-csom-api-windows-powershell-1249#sthash.2ncW42CM.dpuf
 #Get Site Level Permissions if it's unique  

  if($_web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True){ 
     $permissions += (QueryUniquePermissionsByObject $_web $_web "Site" $siteRelativeUrl $siteUrl $siteTitle "");
    }

    #Get all lists in web
  $ll=$_web.Lists
  $ctx.Load($ll);
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  Write-Host "Number of lists" + $ll.Count
  $icount = 0;

  foreach($list in $ll)
  {      
    Load-CSOMProperties -object $list -propertyNames @("RootFolder","Hidden","HasUniqueRoleAssignments");
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $listUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl; 

    #Exclude internal system lists and check if it has unique permissions 

    if($list.Hidden -ne $True)
    { 
      Write-Host $list.Title  -Foregroundcolor "Yellow"; 
      $listTitle = $list.Title; 
    #Check List Permissions 

    if($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
    { 
       $Type = $list.BaseType.ToString(); 
       $permissions += (QueryUniquePermissionsByObject $_web $list $Type $listUrl $siteUrl $siteTitle  $listTitle);

       if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
       { 
            #TODO Get permissions on folders 
           $rootFolder =  $list.RootFolder;
           $listFolders = $rootFolder.Folders;
           $ctx.Load($rootFolder);
           $ctx.Load( $listFolders);

           $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;

           #get all items 
            $spQuery = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
            ## array of items
             $collListItem = @();

            do
            {
                $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery);
                $ctx.Load($listItems);
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;
                $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
                foreach($item in $listItems)
                {
                    $collListItem +=$item 
                }
            }
            while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

            Write-Host  $collListItem.Count 

            foreach($item in $collListItem) 
            {
                Load-CSOMProperties -object $item -propertyNames @("File","HasUniqueRoleAssignments");
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;  

                Load-CSOMProperties -object $item.File -propertyNames @("ServerRelativeUrl");
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery() ;  

                $fileUrl = $item.File.ServerRelativeUrl; 

                $file=$item.File; 

                if($item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
                { 
                  $Type = $file.GetType().Name; 

                  $permissions += (QueryUniquePermissionsByObject $_web $item $Type $fileUrl $siteUrl $siteTitle $listTitle);
                } 
             } 
        } 
    } 
   }
  }
 return  $permissions;
}

if(Test-Path $ExportFileDirectory){
  Write-Host $Username
  Write-Host $password

  $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollectionUrl);
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password);


  $rootWeb = $ctx.Web
  $ctx.Load($rootWeb)
  $ctx.Load($rootWeb.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

   #Root Web of the Site Collection 

   $RootSiteTitle = $rootWeb.Title; 

   $RootWeb = $rootWeb;  
   #array storing permissions
   $Permissions = @(); 

   #root web , i.e. site collection level
   $Permissions += QueryUniquePermissions($RootWeb);
   Write-Host $Permissions.Count;

   Write-Host "Querying Number of webs " $rootWeb.Webs.Count ;  
   foreach($web in $rootWeb.Webs)
   {
     $Permissions +=  (QueryUniquePermissions $web);
     Write-Host "Web :  "  $web.Title "Count" $Permissions.Count
   }

   $exportFilePath = Join-Path -Path $ExportFileDirectory -ChildPath $([string]::Concat($RootSiteTitle,"-Permissions.csv"));

   Write-Host $Permissions.Count

   $Permissions|Select SiteUrl,SiteTitle,Type,RelativeUrl,ListTitle,MemberType,MemberName,MemberLoginName,ParentGroup,Roles|Export-CSV -Path $exportFilePath -NoTypeInformation;
}
else{

Write-Host "Invalid directory path:" $ExportFileDirectory -ForegroundColor "Red";

}
```